# rails calculated field based on 2 columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is probably simple but instead of this:

```
current_cart.line_items.sum(:line_item_total)
```

I prefer to implement it like this:

```
current_cart.line_items.sum(:line_item_unit_price * :quantity)
```

What is the best syntax to build a calculated field based on two fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
current_cart.line_items.sum("line_item_unit_price * quantity")
```

to stick with your second option.

Answer (score 0):

I think following will work

```
def total_price
  line_item_unit_price * quantity
end
```

and then

```
current_cart.line_items.sum(:total_price)
```